# How to enable enableShutterSound on some devices?

Tags: android, android-camera

I used "enableShutterSound" to get rid of the camera shutter sound. The problem is that it works fine on my device, but not on others' devices.

Please can any one help, how can I mute camera shutter sound?

Below is my code.

```
Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        // mCameraFacing is CameraID.
        Camera.getCameraInfo(mCameraFacing, info);
        if (info.canDisableShutterSound) {
            camera.enableShutterSound(false);
        }
```